# Bra-Ket Notation for creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, notation

I'm reading from Landau's book about second quantization and I confused about the bra-ket notation for the creation and annhilation operators.
From the book, annhilation oparator defined as
$$
a_i|N_i\rangle = \sqrt{N_i}|N_i-1\rangle, \tag{eq. 64.5}
$$
and it can be represented in the form of a matrix whose only non-zero element is
$$
\langle N_i-1|a_i|N_i\rangle=\sqrt{N_i}. \tag{eq. 64.6}
$$

The creation operator can be represented by a matrix whose only non-zero element is (eq. 64.7)
$$
\langle N_i|a_i^\dagger|N_i-1\rangle=\sqrt{N_i}. \tag{eq. 64.7}
$$

From here, it says that by direct multiplication of the matrices (eqs. 64.6 and 64.7) it can be proved that
$$
a_i^\dagger a_i = N_i.
$$

The questions are:

1. What is the form of the matrix from eq. 64.6? Is it correct (for $i = 1,2$)?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{N_1}&0\\0&\sqrt{N_2}\end{bmatrix}
$$

2. How do I represent the multiplication of 64.6 and 64.7 using bra-ket notation?
   I'm thinking about this but I don't know if it's correct...

$$
\langle N_i-1|a_i|N\rangle \otimes \langle N_i|a_i^\dagger|N_i-1\rangle = \sqrt{N_i}\cdot\sqrt{N_i}=N_i = \begin{bmatrix}N_1&0\\0&N_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thanks for help!

Comment: The number operator's matrix representation is diagonal; the ladder operators' matrix representations are off-diagonal.

Comment: 1. No and 2. No. You can come up with basically infinitely many "is this correct?" attempts - so please explain *why* do you think this might be the correct way. This enables others to really help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both things are wrong:

A bosonic operator has more than one non-zero element in the matrix representation: the $N$ "part" of the $N_i$ index runs from 0 to $\infty$.

So a "stand-alone" annihilation operator would have a matrix representation like so:
$$
\hat{a} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ...\\  
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & ...\\  
0 & 0  & 0 & \sqrt{3}  &... \\  
0 &0   & 0 & 0 & ...\\  
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots \end{bmatrix}
$$
Or in bra-ket notation:
$$
\hat{a}=\sum_{N>0} \sqrt{N} |N-1\rangle\langle N|
$$
And the number operator would be :
$$
\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\  
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ...\\  
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & ... \\  
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & ... \\ 
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Additionally, the $i$ "part" of the $N_i$ index indicates the subspace in which you're acting on, loosely speaking it's only a label. It can be an integer if you're looking at the EM excitations of a box, for example, in which case it will label the mode number of the box. Or it can be a real number indexing the momenta of phonons for example in a (infinite) crystal.

So what we mean when we write down $\hat{a}_i$ (for an integer index) is a tensor product:
$$
\hat{a}_i = 1 \otimes ... \otimes 1 \otimes \hat{a} \otimes 1 ...  
$$

Where the annihilation operator is at the $i$-th place.
In principle there's a way to write down the matrix form of tensor product of multiple finite matrices (see [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)) but for bosonic operators you can see it would not be possible as they are represented by infinite matrices.

Comment: Thanks!! You really helped!